# Vector implementation in C

Tags: c, vector, dynamic-arrays

I tried googling it, but no solid answer. What are available, still maintained dynamic array implementations for C? What are pros and cons for every one of them, and what is the best one(speed/footprint ratio)? Just asking, so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There's one in the C standard library called `malloc()`.

Comment: You tried googling dynamic array implementations in C and haven't found anything?

Comment: @rid: "no solid answer" :) the sheer mass of answers overwhelms OP.

Comment: @H2CO3, well, `malloc()` doesn't give you a dynamically expanding array, you can use it to write the implementation for such an array (along with `realloc()` and whatever else you might need).

Comment: Actually, i'd do it exclusively with realloc() while utilizing my quest at vamping all C-memory functions as bastardized calls to that glorious little function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GArray](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.35/glib-Arrays.html) from [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.35/glib-data-types.html) does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something like NSMutableArray, from Objective-C, or something like ArrayList from Java, you won't find anything (std C, at least). 
You can create your own dynamic array implementation in C, though. It will take you a few code lines and is not that hard to implement.

All you need to have in mind is Time vs Memory. You can do an implementation that allocates a new array with a bigger size, every time you push/add an element, and then pops it for you in the return or by reference, or you can reallocate memory every time. I don't see big advantages in neither one, except that realloc is a C library function that I think is low level implemented, meaning it is probably faster, and in matters of implementation I would go with the realloc one since it is faster to implement. 
You can even build an api that gives you sorting types and clean all methods.

Now is up to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He said he doesn't want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I read that, but I think he was saying something like keeping it simple, so he don't use some strange code. 

But now I get it. 

sorry.